# Looping data in controller from model codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to prevent the user to create the same username. well my real problem is how to loop a list of data from model in controller. Maybe we know how to loop it in view by using this -> `data['user']` and in view we can call `$user`. but how can we do that in controller layer.

here's my code

## Controller

```
$username = strtolower($this->input->post('name'));

$fixUsername = str_replace(" ",".",$username);

                $counter = 1;
                $list[] = $this->addusermodel->getAllUsername();

                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($list);$i++) {
                    if($list[$i] == $fixUsername) {
                        $counter = 0;
                    }
                }

                if($counter == 0) {
                    $data['result'] = "The username has already been taken";
                    $this->load->view('adduserview',$data);
                } else {
                    $data = array(
                        'Nama' => $this->input->post('name'),
                        'Username' => $fixUsername."@praba",
                        'Password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
                        'created' => date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"),
                        'createdBy' => $createdBy,
                        'lastModified' => date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"),
                        'lastModifiedBy' => $lastModifiedBy
                    );
                    $this->addusermodel->saveUser($data);
                    //$data['Username'] = $listName;
                    $data['message'] = "New user successfully added.";
                    $data['messageContent'] = "The username: ".$fixUsername."@praba". $counter;
                    $this->load->view('successpageview',$data);
                    //redirect('successpageview','refresh');
                }
```

## my model (is like usual)

```
function getAllUsername() {

    $this->db->select('Username');

    $this->db->from('tbluser');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Can't Understand what you really wanted to do ? Can you please elaborate

Comment: well actually I was just to prevent a user to add a new user by validating the same username. I was just validate it in controller, but now I've change it by validating it in model and just return the result (true/false)

Comment: instead of fetching all usernames and looping through all the usernames to check for existence better approach will be to search the username in database table ..so you can create another method in model as below.

function checkUsernameExistance($username) {

    $this->db->select('Username');

    $this->db->from('tbluser');
    $this->db->where('Username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to create another function in your model, which searches your database by `ID`, or by `email`, or by another unique field. If the function returns a `row` - then the user exists. If it returns `nothing` - then add a new user.

Comment: The problem is solved. I follow your suggestion by validating the existing user in the model rather in controller and it worked. nice